# How do I reroute all my traffic (without using VPN)?

Tags: networking, encryption, vpn, proxy

I understand that this could be accomplished with VPN, but the thing is I wish to seek options other than VPN.

What I want to do is to bypass China's GFW, VPN needs a connection establishment phase which makes it easily detectable by the GFW.

I'm looking for options to, on my client machine, a Ubuntu machine per se, channel all traffic to a single service running on the client machine, and then this service gets all these traffic scrambled and sent to my AWS server located in the US.

Alternatively it could also be having all my traffic channeled to 2 services, one for all TCP traffic and the other for all UDP traffic, where I will figure out how to reroute both into the same scrambling service which eventually will all be sent to the remote server.

The scrambling service I'm talking about does not have a connection establishment phase and the traffic is almost indistinguishable from typical https traffic.

So how could I accomplish what I hope to accomplish? VPNs are straightforward and far less complicated but it's also why they are targeted and detectable.

Comment: Ordinary ssh is encrypted. Seems like you are describing an SSH Tunnel.

Comment: @user535733 SSH would be a massive bad idea as the destination of the traffic could be sniffed.